# pyarrow read_table has no 'parquet version' parameter

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

Using pyarrow I can write parquet files of version 2.0.

**pyarrow.parquet.write_table** method has parameter '**version**'. But there is no parameter '**version**' for **pyarrow.parquet.read_table** method. And seems like it only can read parquet files of version 1.0.

How to read parquet files of version 2.0 with pyarrow?

Answer (score 0):

`pyarrow.parquet.read_table` can read files written for Parquet version 2.0 automatically. No need to set parameter, this can be detected by reading the metadata of the given Parquet file.

In your specific case it is hard to give you an exact answer on why it seems that the read isn't working as you did not include any tracebacks in your question.

Comment: Note that version 2.0 files we are writing are actually broken because we are incorrectly writing the DataPageV2 format. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-458

Comment: We also cannot yet read V2 files written by correct Parquet implementations for the same reason.